# SVG Shapes and Involved Mathematics

Tags: soft-question

I have no idea, is this place to ask such question or not. However apparently my question related to math.

My basic aim to understand the mathematic involve in SVG shapes attribute likes "Path, d" manipulation, which would help me to understand calculation and reform the shape as per my requirement.

**Question**

1- Mathematics topics would help me to manipulate as I already aware of Vectors, Matrices, Coordinates System and others, but no idea how it will help to manipulates.

I'm only looking for broad topic(s) to understand the mathematics behind the svg attributes rendering on browser, and the calculation working behind these attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The commands used in SVG paths are defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html). The curves referred to there are explained in the Wikipedia articles on [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and [ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse).